# Automatically add new songs to my Spotify playlist

Tags: spotify

I'd like to add new tracks of specific artists to my playlist "My Favorites". Is there any way to automate this process? The idea is simple whenever artist's new song is added to Spotify, it will also be added to my playlist.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any specific API library? If so, which one & what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I was doing it manually. Checking artist page and if there are new tracks adding them to my playlist. But it is time consuming especially if you want to check several artists.